# Why is this query returning part of itself in the result?

Tags: mysql

I've not come across this before. Here's the query:

```
$query="SELECT 
  CONCAT_WS(' ',
        TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             SUBSTRING(document, 1, INSTR(document, 'Quickstart') - 1 ),
             ' ',
             -8)
        ),'Quickstart',
        TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             SUBSTRING(document, INSTR(document, 'Quickstart') + LENGTH('Quickstart') ),
             ' ',
             5)
        )
)
FROM documents WHERE MATCH(document)
AGAINST('Quickstart' IN BOOLEAN MODE )";
```

And here's the resulting array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [CONCAT_WS(' ',
        TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             SUBSTRING(document, 1, INSTR(document, 'Quickstart') - 1 ),
             ' ',
             -8)
        ),'Quickstart',
        TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             S] => 
Quickstart for set up. 1. Register your
    )
```

The last part it's returning seems to be correct:

```
Quickstart for set up. 1. Register your
```

But why is the query itself returned? Here's the php:

```
if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) send(mysql_error(),"e");
$hitArray=array();      
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) { $hitArray[]=$row; }
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Some explanation: When you execute a query, the query return the name of fields as key in array. In your case, the name of field is `CONCAT_WS....` because you didn't use an alias for this field, just take a look at Ende Neu's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not returning itself, it's the key in the array, try to assign an alias to the `CONCAT_WS` part:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT_WS( ... ) as concatenated
FROM documents WHERE MATCH(document)
AGAINST('Quickstart' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```